# Is there a way to make os.walk return children of a folder, rather than descendants?

Tags: python, os.walk

I have this script.

```py
    for (root, dirs, file) in os.walk("Missions"):
        for f in file:
            if ('py' in f) and (f!="__init__.py"):
                print("TRYING "+f)
                Mission = importlib.import_module(f.split(".py")[0])
                Mission.Init()
```

It is iterating through the "**pycache**" folder inside "Missions" aswell, these python files are descendants. Not children, is there a way to restrict the iteration to direct children only?

Comment: Use `os.listdir('Missions')`

Comment: Thanks, can you post this as an answer for me to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly solution: Explicitly empty `dirs` before you go to the next loop:

```
    for (root, dirs, file) in os.walk("Missions"):
        for f in file:
            if ('py' in f) and (f!="__init__.py"):
                print("TRYING "+f)
                Mission = importlib.import_module(f.split(".py")[0])
                Mission.Init()
        del dirs[:]  # Deletes contents of dirs, so it doesn't go any deeper
```

`os.walk` allows you to mutate the contents of `dirs` to change the set of directories traversed as it goes deeper; this just says "use none of them".

---

Serious solution: Don't bother using `os.walk` when you don't need to go deeper; [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) is faster and more direct (`os.walk` wraps `os.scandir`, it's just invoked recursively on the tree):

```
   for entry in os.scandir("Missions"):
       if entry.is_file():
            if 'py' in entry.name and entry.name != '__init__.py':
                print("TRYING "+f.name)
                Mission = importlib.import_module(f.name.split(".py")[0])
                Mission.Init()
```

Only real difference is that the items from `scandir` are [`DirEntry` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) with more features than a mere string (thus the need to ask for the unqualified name as the `.name` attribute, the ability to test `entry.is_file()`, etc.).

Comment: Hmm... I've always done `dirs[:] = []` instead of `del dirs[:]`. +1 for the tip on os.scandir. Thanks!

Comment: @JustinEzequiel: `del` is infinitesimally more efficient (in that it need not create an unused empty `list`), but otherwise, the behavior is the same either way. `dirs.clear()` also works (but was only introduced in 3.3, so I still tend to use the slice based equivalents if I'm not 100% sure the code will only run on 3.3+).